# Engine Revving/Misfiring - Formerly Running Lean - No Trouble Codes Now

Tags: engine, toyota, cel, fuel-system, emissions

For a few months now my 1999 Toyota Avalon XLS (California model - this apparently affects the emissions specs - I'm in NY however) with around 105k miles has been giving me these totally random periods of revving at idle between 500-750 RPM (sounding like a cat purr) and then continuing that feeling when I'm diving and I'm coasting or easing the engine (but not accelerating).

I ran my code reader on the car and kept getting a P0171 (engine running lean) code so I pretty much (over a period of a few stages) replaced my MAF sensor, tested all the O2 Sensors, replaced a faulty ignition coil - and I replaced my intake manifold gasket and the O Rings for my pistons.

The reasons we had the gaskets and O-Rings replaced is because using a Vacuum Gauge and air compressor allowed us to find some leaks in those regions. Additionally I inspected my timing belt and it looks perfectly fine so I'm pretty sure that isn't really the cause.

While all these replacements cleared the check engine light to date, today I started to experience the revving again - which actually lasted for probably an hour of driving on the highway (even after letting the engine rest for a couple of hours) - then stopped temporarily - and then ten minutes later resumed literally as I pulled into my driveway.

Although I tried running the codes twice today - my reader is now saying everything is A-OK. The serious issue with this problem however is that it happens sporadically so it's hard to recreate the issue at the right time. 
'
As my car is approaching inspection I'm trying hard to fix this issue myself (if possible) because since the P0171 (running lean) code has so many possible causes, it's literally a matter of trial and error for the repair which can cost well over $1k at least from what I was quoted by the dealer (and also from my research on parts and labor online).

Any assistance with this is greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**: Took my car in for inspection and it passed with flying colors but the issue is now even worse. I think the technical term for the symptoms are "hunting" and "surging" - I believe my car is experiencing both.

The engine reving/surging/etc. is now getting worse to the point that my engine has stalled when idling in traffic and also I had to crank the engine a few times to get it started again.

I'm now thinking of changing the fuel filter but I'm not sure if that will help since this issue is always random.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple thoughts on things to check are:

- Failing idle air controller
- Sticking EGR valve

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll have a look at it over the weekend (if not earlier) and post an update as soon as possible. Thanks very much!

Comment: After a few days of driving with the EGR valve disconnected I haven't had the issue come back so it seems that that was the issue. Thanks very much for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

The scanner you have might not be able to read non-active codes. Some of the auto parts chains will do a scan for free. Have them check for codes your scanner might not recover.

Comment: I did take my car to the dealer and I was given primarily the same codes. They did however toss in a few fraudulent codes to try and have me pay for a new O2 sensor (which I already tested before hand). Aside from that the codes matched my reader.